# htaccess redirect url parameter as segment

Tags: .htaccess

Is it possible to redirect url parameters as segments in .htaccess file?

i.e.

```
test/index.php?parameter=MYVALUE
```

to

```
test/MYVALUE/
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes.  Try this:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} parameter=(.*)
RewriteRule test/index\.php test/%1
```

According to "What is matched?" in the [mod_rewrite docs](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriterule), the query string (part after the `?`) is separated out into the `QUERY_STRING` variable, which then has to be tested separately from the main part of the URL.  In `RewriteCond`, the parameter value is captured by the regular expression within the parentheses `(.*)`, and is then available as `%1` in the `RewriteRule`.

Comment: doesn't redirect if I have the \?parameter=(.*) part

Comment: Thanks, can you explain to everyone how the RewriteCond works